# Link the google map markers to post id

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have used the ACF for store google map address. Now i am getting this all maps in an archive page and used it as multiple marker.

Let me give you an example.

Project One has address - India
Project two has address - Uk
Project three has address - USA
Project four has address - China

In a page where all projects are showing like

Project One
Project two
Project three
Project four

In that page i am showing the google map with all the address India, UK, USA, China

Now, I want to get the project link when i click on the Map marker.

That is what i am doing.

```
function projects_location( ) {

    $locations = "[av_google_map height='500px' zoom='14' saturation='-100' hue='' zoom_control='aviaTBzoom_control' maptype_control='' maptype_id='']";

            $args = array( 'post_type' => 'project', 'posts_per_page' => -1 );

            $loop = new WP_Query( $args );  
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                $id = get_the_id();
                $location_map = get_field( 'location_map', $id  );
                $address = explode(',', $location_map['address']);
                $locations .= "[av_gmap_location address='".$location_map['address']."' city='".$address[1]."' country='".$address[2]."' long='".$location_map['lng']."' lat='".$location_map['lat']."' marker='3478' imagesize='40' projecturl ='".get_permalink($id)."'][/av_gmap_location]";
            endwhile;

    $locations .= "[/av_google_map]";
    return do_shortcode($locations);
}
add_shortcode( 'projects-loc', 'projects_location' );
```

See the "projecturl", which is added by me and it also coming in the frontend link this.

```
av_google_map['0']['marker']['0']['projecturl'] = "get the Project url"
```

Now i am trying this to get the url by this

```
jQuery('.gmnoprint img').click( function() {
    obj = av_google_map[0]["marker"][0];
    console.log(obj);
    console.log('lgfgf');
});
```

But it is not working. Please tell me the way to get the url or it is not possible by this way.

Thank you.

Comment: can you show us some html of the output?

Comment: <div class="gmnoprint" title="Keramikou 51, Athens, Greece" style="width: 40px; height: 40px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; opacity: 0.01; cursor: pointer; left: 651px; top: 210px; z-index: 250;"><img alt="" src="http://dev.magnigeeks.com/aiolos/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/marker.png" draggable="false" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 40px; height: 40px; user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; max-width: none;"></div>